# how to keep my product ID in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have two table `Location` and `Car` , what I want is:

- when I click on the picture of the car (View / Cars / view.ctp)
- redirected to the location add form (View / Locations / add.ctp) while keeping the ID of the car I've previously chosen

Comment: Please share your existing code for your cars/view.ctp, carscontroller - view method, locations/add.ctp and locationscontroller add method.

Comment: this is Car/view.ctp :

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code snippets

Comment: <div class="cars view">
 <dl>
  <dt><?php echo __('Id'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['id']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Title'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['title']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Category'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($car['Category']['name'], array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $car['Category']['id'])); ?>

Comment: </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Subcategory'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($car['Subcategory']['name'], array('controller' => 'subcategories', 'action' => 'view', $car['Subcategory']['id'])); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Color'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['color']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Serial'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['serial']); ?>
  </dd>
  
  
 </dl>
</div>

Comment: just one minute, i m new in this forum, i send you my code

Comment: you can edit your answer to format that coda, because, as you can see, in a comment is unreadable. Also, if it not an answer add it to your question not as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to keep ID Model in another Model page in Cakephp 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967788/how-to-keep-id-model-in-another-model-page-in-cakephp-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `id` of the car in the url, using cakephp `Html` helper.

In your `/Views/Car/view.ctp` add

```
echo $this->Html->image("cars/car_id.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Cars",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'add', car_id)
));
```

In your `Controllers/locations_controller.ctp`

```
function add($car_id){
    $this->set('car_id', $car_id);
    //Or do what ever you want with the id
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your view, change this statement

```
echo $this->Html->input("cars/car_id", array(
    "alt" => "Cars",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'add', 'car_id')
));
```

to this

```
echo $this->Html->image("cars/".$car['Car']['id'].".jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Cars",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'add', $car['Car']['id'])
));
```

notice that I'm assuming your images folder structure, tell me if that work.

Comment: i have posted now all class : locationscontroller, carscontroller, cars/view.ctp and locations/view.ctp ,

Comment: no she doesent work, and this is the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967788/how-to-keep-id-model-in-another-model-page-in-cakephp-2

Answer (score 0):

```html
this is LocationsController


<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class LocationsController extends AppController {


 
 public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');
 public $helpers = array(
  'Js',
  'GoogleMap'
  );

 public function index() {
  $this->Location->recursive = 0;
  $this->set('locations', $this->Paginator->paginate());
 }


 public function view($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Location->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Location.' . $this->Location->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('location', $this->Location->find('first', $options));
 }


 public function add($car_id) {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->Location->create();
   $this->set('car_id', $car_id);
   if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  }
  $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
  $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
  $cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users', 'agencies', 'cars'));

  
   
  





 }


 public function edit($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Location->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
   if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  } else {
   $options = array('conditions' => array('Location.' . $this->Location->primaryKey => $id));
   $this->request->data = $this->Location->find('first', $options);
  }
  $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
  $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
  $cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users', 'agencies', 'cars'));
 }


 public function delete($id = null) {
  $this->Location->id = $id;
  if (!$this->Location->exists()) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
  if ($this->Location->delete()) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been deleted.'));
  } else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
  }
  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
 }


 public function admin_index() {
  $this->Location->recursive = 0;
  $this->set('locations', $this->Paginator->paginate());
 }


 public function admin_view($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Location->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Location.' . $this->Location->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('location', $this->Location->find('first', $options));
 }


 public function admin_add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->Location->create();
   if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  }
  $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
  $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
  $cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users', 'agencies', 'cars'));
 }


 public function admin_edit($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Location->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
   if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  } else {
   $options = array('conditions' => array('Location.' . $this->Location->primaryKey => $id));
   $this->request->data = $this->Location->find('first', $options);
  }
  $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
  $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
  $cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users', 'agencies', 'cars'));
 }


 public function admin_delete($id = null) {
  $this->Location->id = $id;
  if (!$this->Location->exists()) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
  if ($this->Location->delete()) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been deleted.'));
  } else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
  }
  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
 }}



and this CarsController






<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
 
class CarsController extends AppController {

 
 public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');

 public $helpers = array('Js', 'GoogleMap');


 
 
 public function admin_index() {
  $this->Car->recursive = 0;
  $this->set('cars', $this->Paginator->paginate());
 }

 public function view($id = null){
  if (!$this->Car->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid car'));
  }
  
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Car.' . $this->Car->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('car', $this->Car->find('first', $options));
   
 }
 public function admin_view($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Car->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid car'));
  }
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Car.' . $this->Car->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('car', $this->Car->find('first', $options));
 }

 
 public function admin_add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->Car->create();
   if ($this->Car->save($this->request->data)) {
    
     


    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The car has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The car could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  }
  $categories = $this->Car->Category->find('list');
  $subcategories = $this->Car->Subcategory->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('categories', 'subcategories'));
  $this->set('categories', $this->Car->Subcategory->Category->find('list'));
 }

 
 public function admin_edit($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Car->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid car'));
  }
  if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
   if ($this->Car->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The car has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The car could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  } else {
   $options = array('conditions' => array('Car.' . $this->Car->primaryKey => $id));
   $this->request->data = $this->Car->find('first', $options);
  }
  $categories = $this->Car->Category->find('list');
  $subcategories = $this->Car->Subcategory->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('categories', 'subcategories'));
 }

 
 public function admin_delete($id = null) {
  $this->Car->id = $id;
  if (!$this->Car->exists()) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid car'));
  }
  $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
  if ($this->Car->delete()) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The car has been deleted.'));
  } else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The car could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
  }
  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
 }

public function index() {
  $this->set('cars', $this->Car->find('all'));
 }

}



and this is cars/view.ctp : 







<div class="cars view">
<h2><?php echo __('Car'); ?></h2>

<?php 


echo $this->Html->input("cars/car_id", array(
    "alt" => "Cars",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'add', 'car_id')
));

 ?>
 <dl>
  <dt><?php echo __('Id'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['id']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Title'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['title']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Category'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($car['Category']['name'], array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $car['Category']['id'])); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Subcategory'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($car['Subcategory']['name'], array('controller' => 'subcategories', 'action' => 'view', $car['Subcategory']['id'])); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Color'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['color']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Serial'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['serial']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Model'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['model']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Picture'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['picture']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Price'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['price']); ?>
  </dd>
  
 </dl>
</div>
<h5><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Rent a Car'), array('controller'=>'locations','action' => 'add')); ?></h5>








and this locations/add.ctp : 








<div class="locations form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Location'); ?>
 <fieldset>
  <legend><?php echo __('Add Location'); ?></legend>
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->input('status');
  echo $this->Form->input('departure_date');
  echo $this->Form->input('expected_return_date');
  echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
  echo $this->Form->input('agency_id');
  echo $this->Form->input('car_id');

  //echo $this->$Session->read('Auth.User.username');
  //echo $this->$Session->read('Auth.Car.id');

 ?>
 
 
 
 </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
 <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
 <ul>

  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Locations'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New User'), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Agencies'), array('controller' => 'agencies', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Agency'), array('controller' => 'agencies', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Cars'), array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Car'), array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```